# Is Possible To Schedule Azure Data Factory Triggers In Synapse While Not in Live Mode

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to schedule Azure Data Factory Triggers in Git hub mode? My understanding is that Scheduled Triggers will on work in Synapse Live Mode.

As you can see from the image, I'm in Git Hub mode. Is it possible schedule triggers while in this mode?

[image]

In an update to the question, I am attempting to create a Trigger in Git Hub mode, however I'm getting the message "Make sure to "Publish" for trigger to be activated after clicking "Save"'. However, when I view my Triggers in Monitor, I can see the Triggers have started even though I haven't published them. Can you let me know if the trigger is actually working or not?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should be able to, I have ADF's with Git using schedule triggers. It might not start until you Publish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible Schedule a Triggers in Azure synapse with Git Hub mode.

Go to New trigger -> select your type `schedule`, `start time` and `time zone.`

[image]

You can check the **Trigger, Pipeline successfully executed and got the output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi, are you saying that it is possible to successfully execute a scheduled trigger in Git hub mode without publishing first? As Scott mentioned, it may not be possible to start a trigger without publising it first. Is that correct?

Comment: Need to publish first , then only possible to execute a scheduled trigger in Git hub mode.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that now. I will let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi, I have just updated the question as I'm not sure if what you mentioned is correct. I think I may have to publish the Trigger for it be activated. Are you sure your trigger worked without first publishing it?

Comment: Hi @Saideep, can you confirm if its possible to start/execute a scheduled trigger without first publishing it?

Comment: The above comments are true as far as I know. The trigger would not start until it is published. So, you have to publish it first for it to be activated.

Comment: @Patterson, The trigger would not start until you published.

Comment: @SaiVamsi, my apologies, I don't think I made myself clear. I was hoping that it would be possible execute a trigger in Git Hub without publishing